# SVG image animated slider

Tags: javascript, svg

I tried to make an image slider using JavaScript and since I needed a complex mask/clip-path for images, I used SVG for clipping the slider(images).

Everything works fine in Firefox, but since I am using SVG for clipping only, and images are in HTML, the clipping `clipPath` in SVG refers to a HTML DOM element (`<img>` tag outside the SVG, not to SVG's `<image>`).

Chrome, IE and Opera doesn't support SVG effects like clip-paths to non-SVG elements.

My questions:

Is there any way to make images slide and being clipped by the SVG object (cross-browser)?

Are there any good SVG-related JavaScript libraries that would ease the solution?

Is this is possible with CSS and PNG graphic? I might change the SVG approach, although the masking/clipping image is really complex.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use the SVG `<image>` tag rather than the html `<img>` tag?

Comment: I want to slide images, and not really good at SVG. Is there a way to horizontally slide `<image>` tags generated dynamically with SVG?

Comment: Sure, manipulate the x attribute of the image.